# Fetching facebook feed data in php from next and previous links

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I need to consume ALL of a users feed data (`/me/feed`) from the FB api, which means i need to consume not only their current data being returned, but also the previous and next links. How do I consume this previous and next data using PHP? Really it comes to a matter of making a subsequent request and consuming the results. How do I do this in PHP? What Id really like to do is get one feed contianing all the users data without a paging option. I tried adding `?limit=99999999` but that still didnt do anything.

Thanks.

Jonathan

Comment: Maybe this could help https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Answer (score 0):

May be this posts will help you..

[Search Facebook events and pagination (Graph API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125191/search-facebook-events-and-pagination-graph-api)

[Facebook Open Graph API: weird behavior of parameter limit while getting a paginated user's news feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553510/facebook-open-graph-api-weird-behavior-of-parameter-limit-while-getting-a-pagin)

[Facebook Graph API: Getting the total number of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435059/facebook-graph-api-getting-the-total-number-of-posts)

[Facebook Graph API pagination is not giving the exact result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356891/facebook-graph-api-pagination-is-not-giving-the-excat-result)